# Agrupar dados com NgFor e GroupBy

Tags: ionic, angular, typescript

Antes no Angular 1 quando eu queria fazer um agrupamento de dados fazia assim:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in me | groupBy: 'role_id'"
```

No meu objeto `me` tinha uma lista de usuários com um campo `role_id` diferente. Daí eu queria fazer assim:

```
# Admin
Diego
João
Maria
```

---

```
# User
Márcio
Alex
Daniella
```

Só com essa linha de comando eu conseguia agrupar.
Mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso no Angular 2 (TypeScript), usando o Ionic.

Que comando é similar a esse para usar no Angular 2?

Estou usando o `NgFor`, mas não consigo fazer o agrupamento.

Comment: Assunto relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248580/how-to-group-data-in-angular-2 e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890413/angular2-typescript-nested-ngfor-without-nested-object

Comment: Até que ajudou. Eu entendi um pouco sobre o assunto. Mas está dando erro num ForEach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os `filters` de AngularJS não passaram para o Angular2 e não existem (muitos) `pipes` que existam por default.

Portanto, primeiro terás que fazer o `@Pipe()` "`group_by`" e depois sim, podes usa-lo.

No entanto, podes sempre *agrupar antes de fazer o `ngFor`* por exemplo quando recebes os dados;

Alguma coisa como:

```
const role = "dev"
const groupedArray = me.filter(entry => entry.role_id === role);
```

e depois iterar sob a `groupedArray` ao invés de `me`:

```
<div *ngFor="let user in groupedArray">
    {{user.name}} {{user.role_id}} {{user.cenas}}
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a definição de `@Pipe`?

Comment: @DiegoSouza `@Pipe()` é o decorator equivalente ao `filter`; Este é uma class, normal, decorada com `@Pipe()` para o Angular saber "o quê é o quê" - da mesma forma que existem os decorators de `@Component()`

Comment: O que é `@Decorator`?

Comment: @DiegoSouza [fica mais facil assim](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/decorators.html)